# Unix Shell Programming: Add a blank line when printing

Tags: shell, unix, for-loop

I am trying to list all the files in the directory but how would you separate each of the files by a blank line? basically each file displayed by separated by a blank line? I am trying to use a for loop? I did try few examples but none really work by spacing a blank lines in between?

```
for i in ls  
do
echo "\n" && ls -l
done

for i in ls  
do
echo "\n" 
ls 
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one:

```
find -printf '%p\n\n'
```

A slightly worse (but more portable) one:

```
ls | sed 's|$|\n|'
```

A more convoluted one:

```
ls | while read f; do
    echo "$f"
    echo
done
```

And here is what [*you should not ever do*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs):

```
for f in `ls`; do
    echo "$f"
    echo
done
```

EDIT:

And, as mentioned by [Nija](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399512/unix-for-loop-help-please/5399566#5399566), the simple shell-only one:

```
for f in *; do
    echo "$f"
    echo
done
```

This one has the disadvantage that on many shells `*` by default expands to itself, rather than an empty string when no files exist.

Comment: I need to use a literal (but escaped) newline to make this command work on my machine - is it variable between unix flavours?

Comment: @Carl Norum: what is your system? It works fine with GNU sed on both bash and tcsh on a Linux system...

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X.  Your answer gives me the list of files with an 'n' added on at the end.

Comment: @Carl: I thought that the `\n` escape for `sed` was mandated by POSIX - apparently I thought wrong. Either that, or the MacOS X `sed` is not POSIX-compliant...

Comment: @thkala, my man page says "A line can be split by substituting a newline character into it.  To specify a newline character in the replacement string, precede it with a backslash."  I'll have to look into the POSIX rules.

Comment: Update - I went and checked POSIX.  It says "A line can be split by substituting a `<newline>` into it. The application shall escape the `<newline>` in the replacement by preceding it by a backslash." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html

Comment: setting `shopt -s nullglob` will remove the disadvantage you speak of. Not POSIX though

Comment: @SiegeX: is that supported in any shell except for bash?

Answer (score 1):

For reference : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

```
for f in /tmp/play/*
do
  echo $f
  echo
done
```

Edited as per comments making it simpler.

Comment: Or simply 'echo' with no argument

Answer (score 1):

`sed` one-liner (or one-char-er):

```
ls | sed G
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are close.  However, using a traditional bash `for` loop with `ls` is dangerous - what happens if your filenames contain spaces?  An easy solution with `awk`:

```
ls | awk '{ print $0 "\n" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how portable the options -d and -t are, but pr is ubiquitous:

```
$ ls | pr -dt
```

Note that any file names with an embedded carriage return will have an extra carriage return added in the output.  (I believe that problem occurs with all of the solutions presented so far.)