# Unix shell for loop

Tags: shell, unix, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix for loop help please?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399512/unix-for-loop-help-please)

I am trying to list the names of all the files in a directory separated by a blank line.  I was using a for loop but after trying a few examples, none really work by adding blank lines in between. Any ideas?

Is there any command which outputs only the first line of a file in unix? How could I only display the first line?

```
for i in ls  
do
echo "\n" && ls -l
done

for i in ls  
do
echo "\n" 
ls 
done
```

Comment: Any bets that aaron and [cid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399512/unix-for-loop-help-please) are taking the same course?

Answer (score 2):

Use `head` or `sed 1q` to display only the first line of a file.  But in this case, if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to capture and modify the output of `ls`.

```
ls -l | while read f; do
  printf '%s\n\n' "$f"
  # alternately
  echo "$f"; echo
done
```

Comment: `for` is the wrong answer here because it breaks on whitespace (actually, on any character in `$IFS`), whereas you want full lines.

Comment: Yep. You should put this below my answer.

Comment: Hmmm... I hope that your filename doesn't contain newlines either or this will break just as badly.  I think that piping through `xargs` before the `while` will fix it.

Comment: @D.Shawley: It won't, because `while` won't work there.  If you need to deal with filenames containing newlines, your first mistake is using `ls` to enumerate them, which is why I didn't bother.  Use globbing to enumerate and separate `ls` commands... but by now things are ugly enough (and slow enough, for one `ls` at a time) to rewrite in something more capable.

Comment: I think that `ls -lB` might do the trick as well.  Using `ls -l | xargs | while read f...` seems to work on my MacBook but I would use `find -print0` with `xargs -0` in most cases :)

Comment: @D.Shawley:  Without `-I`, `xargs` will itself break on whitespace (unless it's quoted).  `-I` will break on lines.  `ls` doesn't have a way to delimit filenames other than newline.  `-B` and a couple other modifiers (which may not be portable) that convert nonprintables to various other forms will work... but you probably lose some localization unless you're careful.  By and large, `ls` is the wrong tool for this and shell scripts are almost as bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
 IFS="
 "
 for i in $(ls /dir/name/here/or/not)
 do
     echo -e "$i\n"  
 done
```

To see the first part of a file use `head` and for the end of a file use `tail` (of course). The command `head -n 1 filename` will display the first line. Use `man head` to get more options. (I know how that sounds).

Comment: Now it actually works. Thanks to geekosaur. Of course, most of these answers will break on pathological cases like newline containing names.

Comment: At last! Made my silly for loop work!

Answer (score 1):

Use shell expansion instead of `ls` to list files.

```
for file in *
do
  echo "$file"
  echo
  if [ -f "$file" ];then
    read firstline < "$file"
    echo "$firstline" # read first line
  fi
done
```

Comment: +1 This is the only correct answer so far.